# remove /public/index.php from Laravel url

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

i am very new to laravel. i've tried following solution to remove '.public/index.php' from Laravel url.

i have one htaccess file on root and other in public folder.

in root file i've written

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in public folder's htaccess file i wrote

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but nothing worked.

still it opens list of directories in laravel

all i want is to convert my url `www.abc.com/public/index.php` into `www.abc.com/` without removing files from public folder to some other folder type solution.

Comment: @RakeshSharma i mentioned in my question 'not the folder change solution..' :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to fix your Document root and the Directory override rule within your sites `.conf` file.

On Ubuntu you will find this in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Your file should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName xxx.com
        ServerAlias www.xxx.com

        ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public/  //<<< add public to your document root
        <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel/public">  ## <<< add the override rule if not exists
         AllowOverride all
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Your laravel app should not be in the document root in any case, as you would allow anybody to access it!

---

**SIDENOTE:**

If you are using plesk or c-panel, you can edit the document root within the domain settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache configuration, set the document root to `/yourapp/public` -- this is meant to be the root web accessible folder; you're opening yourself up to access you may not want if the webroot is anything other than Laravel's `public` folder.